# UK visa issued for parents, but refused for baby

Tags: visas, uk

My wife and I applied for a UK visa and both have visited the UK on a yearly basis since 1999. Now we applied for our daughter who is nine months old, and they gave us visas but refused our daughter with a letter saying we do not meet V4.11, which says:

> Adequate arrangements must have been made for their travel to, reception and care in the UK.

May I ask what exactly do they mean by this? We both got five-year visas issued and they refused our baby?

Documents we included were our business registration, passports with both parents included, our passports, bank statements, insurance policies.
We all hold valid Indian passports and the application is being done in New Delhi, India.

At the time of this visa application we all have valid USA visas, and she’s been there with us for a month. What exactly is the UK trying to do? It’s their country and I must respect their laws, but they might as well have rejected ours too. I would not go anywhere without our daughter.

---

Thanks for the replies, am attaching the letter, also this was a family application and on her form too it was mentioned she will travel with us, and all our passports are updated with each other's names.

We had shown adequate funds in both our accounts above 10K GBP with our home / Office Documents, all without any mortgage. And both of us have had visas since 1990's and have a yearly visit to london for a week or more.

[image: UK LETTER]

Comment: You should add an image of the refusal letter with personal information obscured. UK refusals normally explain why they decided the requirements were not met so the exact contents of the letter are useful.

Comment: The refusal reason sounds like you applied for a unaccompanied minor visa.

Comment: What they are trying to do is to ensure that any minor issued a visa either will be traveling with an appropriate adult, or has other suitable arrangements for their care. I suggest checking very carefully the Under 18 section of your daughter's application. I think you want not traveling alone, and with you and your wife as her accompanying adults. If you filled that out correctly, you need to post the redacted refusal letter.

Comment: kennedy, in my letter i specifically wrote we 3 will travel together, and same was mentioned on the form also :(

Comment: It seems to me that the key fact is that you did not submit a birth certificate (nor any other evidence that you are in fact the child's parents).

Comment: @phoog, thanks for replying i truly assumed all names endorsed on passport was proof enough but yes looks like I messed up big time.

Comment: "*Entry Clearance Officer's have a duty of care to minors*" but not, apparently, to apostrophes.  Sometimes I really despise my government, and its desire to have everything done on the cheap.

Comment: How did it go after you provided the certificate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that you have included the refusal, we can say that they're probably just worried that you're going to bring some unrelated baby into the UK and leave it, causing work and costs for the social services. Simply adding a birth certificate and applying again sounds like it might be enough.

Comment: Thanks would that also take care of their issues from point V4.2 - 4.10?